# Typecheck fails for apparently equal instance definition

Tags: haskell, typechecking

Given the following type definition

```
newtype Constant a b = Constant { getConstant :: a }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

this `Functor` `instance` definition is valid

```
instance Functor (Constant a) where
  fmap _ (Constant x) = Constant x
```

whereas the apparently equivalent `instance` definition

```
instance Functor (Constant a) where
  fmap _ x = x
```

fails with the typecheck error (excerpt)

```
Expected type: Constant a b
  Actual type: Constant a a1
```

using GHC version 8.0.2.

The question is, why these two (apparently equivalent) `instance` definitions behave differently in terms of typechecking.

Comment: It seems to me you are confusing the representation in memory and the type. The representation can be the same, but the type is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might become clearer if we give the constructor a different name, so as to distinguish type-level and value-level:

```
newtype Constant a b = ConstVal { getConstVal :: a }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor (Constant a) where
  fmap _ (ConstVal x) = ConstVal x
```

Now, *why can you not write `fmap _ x = x`*?

`ConstVal` is a *polymorphic constructor*:

```
ConstVal :: a -> Constant a b
```

...i.e.

```
ConstVal :: ∀ a b . a -> Constant a b
```

Though that universal quantifier is optional in Haskell, it is actually important. `ConstVal` has basically two additional, type-level arguments. In other words, this is not just *one constructor* but a whole family of constructors, like

```
ConstValBoolBool :: Bool -> Constant Bool Bool
ConstValBoolInt  :: Bool -> Constant Bool Int
ConstValBoolChar :: Bool -> Constant Bool Char
...
ConstValCharBool :: Char -> Constant Char Bool
ConstValCharInt  :: Char -> Constant Char Int
ConstValCharChar :: Char -> Constant Char Char
...
...
```

All of these actually share the same value-level name `ConstVal`, but to the type system they are all distinct. Explicitly written out, you'd have for instance

```
fmapBoolStringInt :: (String -> Int) -> Constant Bool String -> Constant Bool Int
fmapBoolStringInt _ (ConstValBoolString x) = ConstValBoolInt x
```

Here it's clear that the values on both sides are not actually the same, and hence can not be reduced to `fmapBoolStringInt _ x = x`.

Answer (score 2):

In the `instance Functor (Constant a)` `fmap` has type:

```
fmap :: (b -> c) -> Constant a b -> Constant a c
```

In the expression `fmap _ x = x`, the variable `x` must has different types which isn't possible:

```
fmap _ (x :: Constant a b) = (x :: Constant a c)
```

That typechecker says you.

You could use `unsafeCoerce`, like this:

```
fmap _ x = unsafeCoerce x
```

or

```
fmap _ = unsafeCoerce
```

but this isn't idiomatic way, because even that you know that at this moment the applying of `unsafeCoerce` is safe, you can not guarantee it (in general case) some time later.

However, there is the safe version of [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) since `base-4.7.0.0` (what [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450128/ben) wrote in the him answer).

Also, we can expect that the compiler can optimize the first definition like the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Constant t a -> Constant t b
fmap _ (Constant x) = Constant x
```

Here you deconstruct a value of type `Constant t a` to get a a value `x` of type `t`, then wrap it up in a `Constant` constructor to make a value of type `Constant t b` so you can return it.

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Constant t a -> Constant t b
fmap _ x = x
```

Here you receive a value of type `Constant t a` and return it as a value of type `Constant t b`. That doesn't work.

We can imagine that it *could* work. Since the second type parameter of `Constant` is a phantom parameter, the in-memory representation of those two types are the same, so an in-memory reference to one type could be passed as an in-memory reference to the other type, and everything would work fine.

The GHC runtime actually does this in fact - the `x :: t`, `Constant x :: Constant t a`, and the `Constant x :: Constant t b` will at runtime all be references to the same chunk of memory, and no work is done by this function at all.

But that's a low-level optimisation; semantically they're still different types, and Haskell does not allow a value of one type to be used as a value of a different type.

What you *can* do, since `Constant` is a `newtype`, is use `coerce` (see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Coerce.html) to explicitly convert. That avoids you having to explicitly pattern match and reconstruct. The conversion will be a no-op at runtime (due to the in memory representation being the same). So:

```
fmap _ x = coerce x
```

Or even:

```
fmap _ = coerce
```

Comment: It'll be a no-op either way.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes of course, not sure why I was thinking it wouldn't be.